# Fujitsu Siemens S7010 power problems

Tags: power-supply, laptop

I know this is a bit of a long shot, but please bear with me. My Fujitsu Siemens S7010 notebook no longer powers up.

Presently, when I plug in the AC adapter, an AC icon [image] briefly appears in the LED display, then disappears after about 1 second. The same goes for plugging in the battery: a full battery indicator [image] lights up for 1 second, then everything is dead again. No display, no fan; pressing the power button has absolutely zero effect, except if I *immediately* hit the power button after the indicator disappears. In this case, the AC indicator lights up for a fraction of a second, only to disappear for good.

The machine has been having increasing difficulties getting started over the past week or so. I backed everything up because I was worried the PSU was giving out, and sure enough, that day has arrived. After disassembling it, however, I couldn't find any broken solder joints or burnt out capacitors.

I've tried removing and reinserting the HDD and DDR banks; no dice. Also detatching *all* devices has no effect.

Is there any hope for this machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation, I have considered it totaled as I suspect that the PSU is burnt out. Unfortunately, the PSU is embedded into the main board, so the cost of replacing it would exceed the value of the machine.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably right that the PSU has given out, and laptop mainboards are rarely worth replacing.